# How to implement kvo in Mathematica 10?

Tags: programming

Key value coding and observing is something that other languages do well, like objective-c for instance. What's the best way to achieve something similar in Mathematica (if at all possible)? That is, how can you trigger an event based on a certain variable's value changing without relying on front-end dynamics...

Comment: One idea would be to not use `CompoundExpression` in your programs, but, say, `AngleBracket` and do something like `Unprotect[AngleBracket]; 
Precedence[AngleBracket] = 10.; SetAttributes[AngleBracket, HoldAll];` and then define `AngleBracket[expr1_, expr2_, expri___]` in such a way that after each evaluation of an argument a list of `KVO` pure function triggers would be checked.  You could also add quite effective debugging this way I guess. Sorry to not work this out more, but time is short these days ...

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea Rolf! thanks... it seems that  TrackedSymbol sort of does kvo under the hood, but it too opaque and only works with Dynamics, actually the answer is quite simple

Comment: @LeonidShifrin The observer design pattern question you referenced is a great resource, my desire is simply to execute pre and post update blocks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplistic way to do what I needed, that is, running some code before and after the variable updates:

```
    ClearAll[kvo, r];
    SetAttributes[kvo, {HoldAll}];
    kvo[v_, pre_, post_] := ((v /: Set[v, x_] := (pre[v]; v := x; post[x])))

    kvo[r, Print["before update, var = ", #] &, 
     Print["after update, var = ", #, "\n"] &]
    Do[r = i^2, {i, 3}]
```

outputs

```
before update, var = r
after update, var = 1

before update, var = 1
after update, var = 4

before update, var = 4
after update, var = 9
```

Thanks @leonid for the link, very helpful, but that solution is a bit overkill for my needs....